# Efficiently attaching a Jekyll::Document to another

Tags: ruby, jekyll

In a Jekyll generator plugin, I'm attaching related pages to a main page.

My concern is that I may end up with some kind of recursive loop and or that I am bloating the page.

I could alternately attach a hash of the values I select from the subpage or the subpage cast to an interface with the desired api. (That is if Ruby has this feature.)

Comment: Looks like you can't cast to an interface. Casting to a different class seems more complex than creating a hash.

Comment: Will test speed of build with a both hash and reference to object